# how to make relationship between 2 tables using Node.js Express.js and Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, sequelize.js

Hi guys I'm in process of developing a web application using angular and node.js
in the backend part, I used express.js and Sequelize ORM to make the server and the database but while I'm creating the tables I got some problem which is how to how to make a relationship between 2 tables
Can you help me guys !!
and thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add your code then it is easy to identify where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize supports the standard associations betwen tables: One-To-One, One-To-Many and Many-To-Many.

To do this, Sequelize provides four types of associations that should be combined to create them:

- HasOne association
- BelongsTo association
- HasMany association
- BelongsToMany association

If you want more in detail info watchout sequelize docu: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Answer (score 0):

For a one-one relationships you define the two tables and then define the relationship

```
db.Table2.Table1 = db.Table2.belongsTo(db.Table1, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: “sharedId"
    }
});
db.Table1.Table2 = db.Table1.hasOne(db.Table2, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: "sharedId"
    }
});
```

For one-many relationships, you would change hasOne to hasMany or belongsTo to belongsToMany.